# How to fix Excel grey worksheet

Tags: excel

i have an excel sheet that is grey for some reason. The data seems to be there, but i cant view it. See the picture below. I tried so far going to "normal" view, but that didnt help. Any ideas what caused this and how to get the data visible again?
[image]

Comment: Put a full print so we can see the tabs here

Comment: Sorry i actually cant show entire screen. Basically i have multiple worksheets and they are visible. Even this sheet is visible and accessable in the lower tab, but its grey for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your entire worksheet is hidden. Check your menu in order to unhide everything again.

Comment: What menu are you referring to, right click on the worksheets tab (for example, right click on Sheet1, says i have no sheets hidden (unhide is greyed out)